# Regarding click() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code. I want to click on the button and alert its id. The button is contained in a div. Both button and div have a `click()` bound to them.

**Problem**: If I click the button the id of button is alerted and then id of div is also alerted afterwards. I want to prevent the id of div from being alerted.

**Code**:

```
<html>
<body>
    <style type="text/CSS">
        #mydiv{
            border: 1px dashed blue;
            width: 90px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me"></input>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code.js**:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
            alert($('#myDiv').attr('id'));
        });

$('#myButton').click(function(){
            alert($('#myButton').attr('id'));
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) method of the event object to prevent it from bubling upwards.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: You were the first to answer?

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer. Atleast I can give +1 to all the answers, they all are same.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Use

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq2g0549/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) as shown :

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){ // the extra parameter here is the event object
   e.stopPropagation(); // stops event bubbling up
   alert($(this).attr('id')); // the this in the current scope is the myButton element so you can just use this.id
});
```

Comment: Would `prop` be better or not?

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr in some circumstances. However, since `id` is a string anyway, I'd think in this case not? Maybe prop would be quicker anyway, not sure.